# Adding a read more link to WordPress truncation

Tags: php, wordpress, truncation

I am truncating the content field of a page which I am calling into another page - in similar format to how the posts appear on the blog index page in default Wordpress.

What I want to do is truncate the post and include a "... read more" link to those pages which have a lot of content. I have truncation working nicely - but can't add in the  to the code where I specifiy what characters to display to truncate the page... Code example below

```
<p><em><?php $content = $project->post_content; echo mb_strimwidth($content, 0, 850, '...');?></em></p>
```

The  code I need to include is:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $project->ID ); ?>">Read more...</a>
```

How can I add the  read more link after the "..."s?

The issue is that wordpress is basically not allowing the PHP inside the  to work... it just renders it as the link target... e.g.

```
<?php echo get_page_link( $project->ID ); ?>
```

So rather than allowing the PHP to get the right link url, it just publishes the link as per the PHP code...

Cheers

dubbs.

Answer (score 0):

OK - worked it out. Solution as below:

Set a variable:

```
<?php
ob_start();
echo get_page_link( $project->ID );
$chicken = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
?>
```

Then call the chicken variable into the  as below:

```
<p><em><?php $content = $project->post_content; echo mb_strimwidth($content, 0, 850, '...&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="'.$chicken.'">Read more</a>');?></em></p>
```